# Flag history page shows no title/link for flags on collection comments

Tags: bug, status-review, comment-flags, flag-history, collections

For flags on post comments, there's a `div.answer-summary > div.answer-link > a`. For flags on collection comments, there's no such anchor. There's no indicator of what was flagged or what the flagged thing belonged to. Please add it.